# IBOutlets in container view are nil

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, iboutlet

I'm working on an app that involves highlighting song lyrics at the proper time in the song. My method of doing this isn't great, but it worked until I moved the view controller with the lyrics into a container view in the presenting view controller. The flow of the app goes like this: press the play button and the view controller containing the lyrics comes into view and a timer is set off and increments a counter. When the counter is between certain times, the UILabel containing the appropriate word has it's text color property changed. This worked fine before, but now that it is in a container view the IBOutlets pointing to the labels are nil. If I look in storyboard though, I can clearly see that they are connected.  However, I inserted a button with an IBAction on the container view controller and through that method I am able to change the background color of any of the labels. So does anyone have an idea why the labels would be nil?

Here's where I start the timer:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02f target:self selector:@selector(highlightWord) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and highlightWord is here(definitely not the prettiest code but I couldn't think of a better way. The names of the properties refer to the word I want to highlight) It's pretty repetitive so you shouldn't have to read through the whole thing. Just know that when I set a break point in this method, all of the IBOutlets are nil.Also, "seconds" is an integer counter that I set to zero when I initialize the timer:

```
- (void)highlightWord {
    // 1
    if (!paused) {
        [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
        seconds += 0.02;
        NSLog(@"%f", seconds);

        if (seconds >= 0 && seconds <=3.48) {

            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];

            self.cheer.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        } else if (seconds >= 3.74 && seconds <= 3.8) {

            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.cincinnati.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 5.1 && seconds <= 5.2) {

            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.cincy.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 5.4 && seconds <= 5.5) {

            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.will.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 5.8 && seconds <= 6.1) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.win.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 6.8 && seconds <= 7.0) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.fight1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 7.04 && seconds <= 7.2) {

            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.to1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 7.36 && seconds <= 7.4) {

            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.the1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 7.5 && seconds <= 7.7) {

            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.finish.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 8.46 && seconds <= 8.5) {

            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.never.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 8.98 && seconds <= 9.0) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.give1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 9.28 && seconds <= 9.34) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.inLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 9.4 && seconds <= 9.5) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.rah1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 9.503 && seconds <= 9.6) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.rah2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 9.61 && seconds <= 9.7) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.rah3.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 10.15 && seconds <= 10.36) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.youLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if ( seconds >= 10.38 && seconds <= 10.46){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.do1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 10.78 && seconds <= 10.9) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.your.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 10.98 && seconds <= 11.2) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.best.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 11.4 && seconds <= 11.6) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.boys1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 11.7 && seconds <= 11.8) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.weWillLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 11.85 && seconds <= 12.0) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.do2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 12.1 && seconds <= 12.3) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.the2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 12.6 && seconds <= 12.8) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.rest.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 12.98 && seconds <= 13.1) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.boys2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 13.4 && seconds <= 13.6) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.onward.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 14.2 && seconds <= 14.3) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.to2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 14.3 && seconds <= 14.5) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.victory.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 16.8 && seconds <= 16.9){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.go1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 17.58 && seconds <= 17.62){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.red.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 18.6 && seconds <= 18.7) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.go2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 19.2 && seconds <= 19.3){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.black.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 20.3 && seconds <= 20.4){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.go3.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 21.2 && seconds <= 21.3){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.bearcats.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 22.03 && seconds <= 22.200){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.fight2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 22.24 && seconds <= 22.400){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.fight3.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 22.8 && seconds <= 22.9){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.fight4.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 23.4 && seconds <= 23.5){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.give2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 23.51 && seconds <= 23.6){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.me.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 23.61 && seconds <= 23.7){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.a1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 23.8 && seconds <= 23.9){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.B.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 24.4 && seconds <= 24.5){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.e.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 25.5 && seconds <= 25.6){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.a.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 26.0 && seconds <= 26.1){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.r.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 27.15 && seconds <= 27.3){
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.c.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 27.5 && seconds <= 27.6) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.a2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 27.9 && seconds <= 28.1) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.t.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >=28.3  && seconds <= 28.4) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.s.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 28.8 && seconds <= 28.9) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.go4.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if (seconds >= 29.3 && seconds <= 29.5) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.UC.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 30.4 && seconds < 42.08) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
        }else if(seconds >= 44.0 && seconds <= 44.8) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.B.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 45.7 && seconds <= 45.8) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.e.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 47.4 && seconds <= 48.0) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.a.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 49.05 && seconds <= 50.0) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.r.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 50.6 && seconds <= 50.8) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.c.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 52.4 && seconds <= 52.5) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.a2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 54 && seconds <= 54.2) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.t.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 55.8 && seconds <= 56.2) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.s.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 57.44 && seconds <= 57.5) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.B.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 57.84 && seconds <= 57.9) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.e.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 58.1 && seconds <= 58.16) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.a.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 58.6 && seconds <= 58.7) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.r.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 59.06 && seconds <= 59.2) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.c.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 59.46 && seconds <= 59.5) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.a2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 59.9 && seconds <= 60.0) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.t.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 60.2 && seconds <= 60.3) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.s.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 60.6 && seconds <= 60.8) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.B.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 62.26 && seconds <= 62.3) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.e.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 63.9 && seconds <= 63.98) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.a.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 65.5 && seconds <= 65.58) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.r.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 67.36 && seconds <= 67.4) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.c.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 69.02 && seconds <= 69.1) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.a2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 70.7 && seconds <= 70.78) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.t.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 72.4 && seconds <= 72.48) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.s.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }



        else if(seconds >= 74.1 && seconds <= 74.3) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.B.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 74.5 && seconds <= 74.6) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.e.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 75.0 && seconds <= 75.2) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.a.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 75.4 && seconds <= 75.6) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.r.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 75.8 && seconds <= 75.98) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.c.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 76.2 && seconds <= 76.4) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.a2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 76.6 && seconds <= 76.8) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.t.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 77.0 && seconds <= 77.2) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.s.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else if(seconds >= 77.3 && seconds <= 77.9) {
            [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
            self.B.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.e.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.a.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.r.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.c.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.a2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.t.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            self.s.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }


    // 2
    if (seconds >= 79) {
        [self setAllLyricsToWhite];
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }
}
```

And just for test purposes, here's the IBAction hooked up to a button that is actually able to reference the labels. They're not nil in here:

```
- (IBAction)highlightLabelTest:(id)sender {
    [self.label setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT

After printing out the description of one of several of the labels in viewDidLoad, this is what I saw in the console:

```
Spirit[18200:70b] *****Label:<UILabel: 0xc402050; frame = (58 23; 68 21); text = 'Cheer'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc4020f0>>
2013-11-20 21:32:49.200 Bearcat Spirit[18200:70b] *****Label:(null)
2013-11-20 21:32:49.200 Bearcat Spirit[18200:70b] *****Label:(null)
2013-11-20 21:32:49.200 Bearcat Spirit[18200:70b] *****Label:(null)
```

So it appears that it starts off set and then somehow gets set to null. I'm confused why viewDidLoad would be called four times though.

Here's what I see if I set a breakpoint anywhere in the method that my timer is using(highlightWord):

[image: debugger output]

Comment: When you say "container view", do you mean the object in IB called a container view that gives you an embedded controller, or are you using that phrase loosely? Do you have more than one controller, or is all the code you posted in the same one.

Comment: The container I'm referring to is the object you drag out in IB. It lets me contain another view controller, and it is in this contained view controller that I placed the code above. This contained view controller is also where the properties are hooked up

Comment: So did you log to check that the labels are nil, or are you assuming that because the color doesn't change? Also, if you log one of the labels in viewDidAppear of this container controller, is it nil there?

Comment: Use breakpoints to debug.  Use NSLog(@"Label T = %@", self.t == nil? @"T is nil": @"T is NOT nil"); to check if its actually nil or not. When you have timer... its good idea to put bunch of NSLog statements to see what is actually going on.

Comment: When I set a breakpoint in any of the places where I am trying to change the text color, the debugger tells me they are nil. But they aren't in the IBAction method. I'll check in viewDidAppear